# How to shift light to a longer wavelength / lower frequency energy level so that it becomes a different "color"?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, lenses, wavelength

I need to shift light from a certain wavelength/frequency to another, lower, level. For example, green light down to yellow or orange.

[image: wikipedia spectral colors]

I want to reduce the energy level of the transmitted light, for example, by a wavelength between 75 and 100 nanometers (roughly 50 to 120 THz).

How can this be done via medium changes? I.e., altering glass (adding a material or element or heating/cooling, etc.) or using some medium that could drop the energy level of the incoming light down to a lower frequency or by applying a magnetic/electromagnetic field?

Comment: You might consider a Raman shifter.

Comment: Raman shifters are interesting, but are they not very lossy? This particular use case requires a lossless or near-lossless method of retaining the "image" (input array) if possible...

Comment: A phosphor might do the trick .... easy to convert blue to green, yellow or red.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting, can you elaborate on this further @PhysicsDave? I'm not sure of flexibility - would it be possible to drop down from violet and perhaps even high range UV with phosphor?

Comment: All white leds use phosphor to convert a portion of blue or uv light to green, yellow red in a broad spectrum.  The blue plus the emitted colours make the white, you can wiki phosphor or led .....

Comment: That is really good to know @PhysicsDave. Thanks for sharing that insight.